# how to make a DIV unfocusable?

Tags: javascript, html, focus

I met a problem about HTML rendering.

In dir="rtl" document of IE7, when JavaScript tries to set focus to a DIV element(with oElement.focus() method), the rendering turns to mess. The context is very complicated, so I suppose the easiest fix is to make the DIV unfocusable?

Is there any way to make a DIV not be focused?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make an HTML element non-focusable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9152096/how-to-make-an-html-element-non-focusable)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The `<div>` should not be capable of receiving focus unless you have added **tabIndex**.

If you have added `tabIndex`, you should remove it by

```
document.getElementById("yourElement").removeAttribute("tabIndex");
```

Comment: I know this is super old, but my experience has shown that Firefox will allow a div to get focus even if it does not have a tabIndex.  (Just added as an FYI for other googlers.)

Comment: Note that divs with `contenteditable="true"` can also receive focus.

Answer (score 25):

**Additionally**, If you want to make a focussable element(form input elements etc.) as unfocussable. You can set :

```
tabIndex = "-1"

document.getElementById("yourElement").setAttribute("tabIndex", "-1");
```

Comment: This will not make the element unfocusable though, it will just make it unreachable with keyboard navigation. Clicking the element would still focus it.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if you can make an element 'un-focusable', but you can certainly un-focus it at a specific point in time using its [`blur`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/blur_event) method:

```
document.getElementById("myElement").blur();
```

**EDIT:**

I think you can make an element 'un-focusable' by defocusing it every time it is focused. You can accomplish this via:

```
document.getElementById("myElement").onfocus = function() {
    this.blur();
};
```

...or (using inline Javascript in your HTML):

```
<div onfocus="this.blur();"></div>
```

Steve

Comment: To blur it, it means the focus is already on it, right?
How to disable focus to be set on it?

Comment: I'm not sure whether it is possible to make an element 'un-focusable'. Sorry for not reading your question carefully!

Answer (score 0):

**Below is the some way to make DIV unfocusable using jquery.**

```
    //  Set the tabindex atribute to -1.
        1)$("divid").attr('tabindex','-1');
    //  Remove the tabindex atribute if exists.
        2) $("divid").removeAttr('tabindex');
   //   This is third way.
        3) $("divid").blur();
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS-only solution from one of my past projects

```css
/* Prevents all mouse interactions */
.disabled-div {
  opacity: 0.5;
  pointer-events: none;
}

/* Prevents all other focus events */
.disabled-div:focus,
.disabled-div:focus-within {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<h1>CSS Only Disable with Prevent Focus</h1>

<input placeholder="Normal text field">
<br><br>
<input class="disabled-div" placeholder="Disabled text field">
<br><br>
<input placeholder="Normal text field">
<br><br>
<input class="disabled-div" placeholder="Disabled text field">
<br><br>
```

Flickers slightly when it receives focus. That is because when it receives focus, visibility is set to 'hidden' and focus is lost and visibility is set back to 'visible' again. This is actually good because the user now has some idea where focus is while going over disabled fields...

Answer (score -3):

An easy fix could be done by adding CSS :

```
div_selector{
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Or By adding same css via jQuery :

`$(div_selector).css('pointer-events', 'none');`

Comment: That makes it unclickable, which is different than unfocusable.

Comment: downvoting, because as @Slbox said, pointer-events involve the cursor and it will still be interacted with the keyboard