# Is there a way to disable focus on div and its child nodes?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Assuming we have a DOM:

```
...
<div>
  // child nodes
</div>
<div id="needsToNotBeFocusable"> 
  // child nodes 
</div>
...
```

Is there a way to make `<div id="needsToNotBeFocusable">` and its child nodes not focusable?

Setting `tabindex="-1"` on each child node will ruin already existing tabindexes.

Comment: Can you explain more about your question? child nodes should not be a highlight?

Comment: Is `needsToNotBeFocusable` not visible or something?

Comment: @karthicknagarajan child nodes shouldn't be able to receive keyboard focus, just like if every single one of them has attribute `tabindex="-1"`

Comment: If the div in question is within a single form, check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17186342/1394872

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Make an HTML element non-focusable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9152096/make-an-html-element-non-focusable)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, there's a distinction between "not-focusable by tab key" and "never-focusable (programmatically, by click, or by tab)". The former is achieved with setting the `tabindex="-1"` attribute, the latter by adding a `disabled` attribute.

```css
input {display:block}
```

```html
<input>
<input>
disabled: <input disabled>
tab -1: <input tabindex="-1">
<input>
<input>
```

> Setting tabindex="-1" on each child node will ruin already existing tabindexes.

I don't see what you mean. How could tabindex be ruined for a un-tab-focusable element?

> Is there a way to make  and its child nodes not focusable?

Div's can't be focused in the normal sense (though they can be scrolled to). But making its children unfocusable simply requires iterating its children (possibly multiple levels deep) and either settint `tabindex` or `disabled`.

```js
let recursiveUnfocusable = el => {
  el.disabled = true;
  [...el.children].forEach(recursiveUnfocusable);
};

let div = document.querySelector('#needsToNotBeFocusable');
recursiveUnfocusable(div);
```

```html
...
<div>
  <input><input><input>
</div>
<div id="needsToNotBeFocusable"> 
  <input><input><input>
  <div>
    <input><input><input>
  </div>
</div>
...
```

Comment: *"Setting tabindex="-1" on each child node will ruin already existing tabindexes."* means OP has tab indexes set for when they are focusable.

Comment: Still don't get it. How can an element be unfocusable and have a 'tab index set for when they are focusable'?

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  
> I don't see what you mean. How could tabindex be ruined for a un-tab-focusable element?  
Child nodes of `<div id="needsToNotBeFocusable">` have their own tabindexes, so iterating all child nodes and setting tabindexes to -1 will overwrite already existing structure.

Comment: But why do you need an **unfocusable** child element to have `tabindex` set?

Comment: Because they still exist on the page. Upon let's say, pressing a button `<div id="needsToNotBeFocusable">` should be focusable again

Comment: ah, so you want them unfocusable **temporarily**. I don't see how anyone could have guess this without you saying so. In that case, just store the previous tabindex to another attribute, and then restore it.

Comment: `[...el.children].forEach(recursiveUnfocusable);` so no matter what the element is you are adding the attribute? yikes

Answer (score 4):

You can now achieve this by adding the [inert](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/inert) attribute to `<div id="needsToNotBeFocusable">`:

```css
input {display:block}
```

```html
<div>
    inside plain div: <input>
<div>
<div id="needsToNotBeFocusable" inert>
    inside inert div: <input>
</div>
<div>
    inside plain div: <input>
<div>
```

> The inert global attribute is a Boolean attribute indicating that the browser will ignore the element. With the inert attribute, all of the element's flat tree descendants (such as modal s) that don't otherwise escape inertness are ignored. The inert attribute also makes the browser ignore input events sent by the user, including focus-related events and events from assistive technologies.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use data attributes to hold the tab index and set it when you enable it.

```js
document.querySelector("#inp1").addEventListener("input", function() {
  var enabled = this.value.length > 0
  document.querySelectorAll("#needsToNotBeFocusable [data-index]").forEach(function(elem) {
    elem.tabIndex = enabled ? elem.dataset.index : -1
  })
})
```

```html
<div>
  <input id="inp1" tabIndex="1" placeholder="tab 1" />
</div>
<div id="needsToNotBeFocusable">
  <input data-index="2" tabIndex="-1" placeholder="tab 2" />
  <input data-index="5" tabIndex="-1" placeholder="tab 5" />
  <input data-index="3" tabIndex="-1" placeholder="tab 3" />
  <input data-index="6" tabIndex="-1" placeholder="tab 6" />
  <input data-index="4" tabIndex="-1" placeholder="tab 4" />
</div>
<input tabIndex="7" placeholder="tab 7"/>
```

Comment: Nice suggestion, but inapplicable in my case since `<div id="needsToNotBeFocusable">` child nodes actually form a huge DOM tree so that's why iterating over it wasn't an option for me from the beginning since it can really hurt performance.

Comment: well there is not much you can really do. Either you disable the components, remove them from the page, or you remove the tab index.